# VBA code to make a pivot table is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with my pivot tables. For some reason, this code was working this morning but now it is not. Here is my code up until the error.

```
Dim WSD2 As Worksheet

 Set WSD2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
           Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
  WSD2.Name = "POS Info"


'--------------------------------------------------

'        Step 2: Create the pivot table

'--------------------------------------------------

Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim FinalCol As Long
Dim StartPT As String
Dim BottomRowStart As Range ' this is for pivot table
Dim BottomRowEnd As Range ' this is for pivot table
Set WSD = Worksheets("aggregateData")




' Select the data for pivot table

FinalRow = WSD.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
FinalCol = WSD.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = WSD.Cells(2, 1).Resize(FinalRow, FinalCol)
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

'Where do I want the pivot table to start

StartPT = WSD2.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Set WSD2 = Worksheets("POS Info")

'Begin to Create the Pivot Table

Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPT, TableName:="POS Data")
```

The last line is where I get the following error message:

> "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Comment: As far as I can tell, `TableDestination` must be a `Range`, not an address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @GSerg said in the comment, TableDestination needs to be a range instead of an address.

Right now you assign an address to the TableDestination, which really is just a string (text) saying "$A$3" or similar. You need to change this to `TableDestination:=WSD2.range(StartPT)` and then you code should work.

Note that it is possible that this worked previously but not any more because you may have added more worksheets to the document. Then when VBA tries to understand the address "$A$3" it cannot decide which worksheet to use and hence throws an error. It's therefore always smart to be quite clear when referring to ranges, and to do it via their workbook.worksheets path. See [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/410603-pivot-table-destination-problem.html) for more.

Comment: Hey Burge and Serg, I still get an error message that says "Method 'Range' of Object_worksheet failed". Any suggestions?

Comment: Your address might be strange. Try to use f8 to go through the code step-by-step. Once you have assigned value to StartPT, hover over it to see what the assigned value is. It should be an address string. See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008033/vba-method-range-of-object-worksheet-failed-suddenly-coming-up-when-running-c

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working still. I am confused because this worked yesterday and I have no changed it since.

Comment: The problem occurs when I am creating the the new worksheet. If I already have my worksheet in place and not get the macro to create it for me, the code works fine.

Comment: I figured it out. My PTStart was a string, not a range. I think that was the issue because I modified it to work,