# Running a Macro works correctly in debug mode, but not when I click button to run

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, that basically copies databases from some files in a folder and pastes in my workbook.

It is supposed to clean everything before starting, and it does when I run from console, hitting F8 and going through it, but when I click the button to which I have assigned the Macro, it does not clean the old base before getting the new ones, then I get old data and then new data below it.

Do you know what can cause it?

Thank you!

```
Sub Atualizar_B_Un_Time()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro execution
    Application.EnableEvents = False    'turn off other macros for now
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'turn off system messages for now


    Dim base_5 As Workbook
    Dim plan_5 As Worksheet
    Dim aux As String
    Dim caminho As String
    Dim nome_arquivo_5 As String
    Dim destino_5 As Worksheet
    Dim dia As String

    Set destino_5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B_Un_Time")
    caminho = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    nome_arquivo_5 = Dir(caminho & "\IC_Reports_AgentUnavailableTime*.xlsx")


    destino_5.Range("H2:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).UnMerge
    destino_5.Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    destino_5.Range("H2:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents


    Do While nome_arquivo_5 <> ""
        aux = caminho & "\" & nome_arquivo_5
        Set base_5 = Workbooks.Open(aux, Local:=True)
        Set plan_5 = base_5.Sheets(1)


        dia = Mid(nome_arquivo_5, InStr(nome_arquivo_5, "-") + 1, 2)


        plan_5.Range("A2:E" & plan_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
            Destination:=destino_5.Range("H" & (destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1))


        destino_5.Range("F" & (destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1) & ":" & "F" & _
            (destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = Format(Now, "mm/") & dia & Format(Now, "/yyyy")


        base_5.Close savechanges:=False


        nome_arquivo_5 = Dir
    Loop


    If IsEmpty(destino_5.Range("A" & destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)) Then
    destino_5.Range("A2:E2").Copy Destination:=destino_5.Range("A" & (destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1) _
        & ":" & "E" & destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)
    destino_5.Range("G2").Copy Destination:=destino_5.Range("G" & (destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1) & ":" & _
        "G" & destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)


    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(destino_5.Range("A" & (destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1))) Then
    destino_5.Rows((destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1) & ":" & destino_5.Cells(Rows.Count, "A") _
        .End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Delete
    End If


    destino_5.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    destino_5.Cells.Font.Size = 8
    destino_5.Rows.RowHeight = 11.25

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True    'turn system alerts back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True     'turn other macros back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True   'refreshes the screen

End Sub
```

Comment: `destino_5.Range("H2:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).UnMerge` is `destino_5` the active sheet, if not `cells(rows.count` may be referring to the activesheet

Comment: @Davesexcel WOW, THAT WAS IT!! How could I not see?! Thank you very much. Actually, you just told me the same thing as SJR, but I did not see before. Thank you both!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA method 'range of object' \_Worksheet failed suddenly coming up when running code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008033/vba-method-range-of-object-worksheet-failed-suddenly-coming-up-when-running-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you haven't added a sheet references everywhere. and hence are referencing the active sheet. Try amending that section thus (note the dots):

```
With destino_5
    .Range("H2:L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).UnMerge
    .Range("F2:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("H2:L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: Did not work.

Referencing using a With block or directly into the line both gave me the same problem =/

Comment: Ooooooops, did not see the dot before Cells, even you telling me to note the dots..
Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!